# PHP to select records from one table based on match of value contained in string in second table in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, string-matching, multiple-tables

For a User on my site (identified as $fb_user_id), am trying to pull all product records where a product owner id (prod_owner_fb_id) in the Products Table ($productstable) matches one of the values in the User's friends list ($usertable.fb_friends) column which is stored as comma delimited string (varchar).

Results from query below using IN clause only successful at pulling record if single value in fb_friends column, not if multiple values.

Am an amateur, so not sure if I've over complicated issue or simply syntax/user error.  Appreciate any help.

My query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $productstable, $usertable WHERE $usertable.fb_user_id = $fb_user_id AND $productstable.prod_owner_fb_id IN ($usertable.fb_friends)";
```

Example Data:

User Table - usertable (both fields varchar):

```
fb_user_id          fb_friends

111111111111111 21709455,222222222222222,82101450,503046016,507...
222222222222222 111111111111111, 697041857,333333333333333,1000006...
333333333333333 111111111111111,1205332730,222222222222222
```

Product Table - productstable (both fields varchar):

```
product_id     prod_owner_fb_id 

A            111111111111111
B            111111111111111
C            222222222222222
```

Note - also unsuccessful with LIKE clause - no records found, no errors:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $productstable, $usertable WHERE $usertable.fb_user_id = $fb_user_id AND $productstable.prod_owner_fb_id LIKE '%" . $usertable1.fb_friends . "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fb_friends column is not the most efficient way to store searchable data in a WHERE clause, especially as you scale.  Here's one way to solve this:

Consider starting a new table (friendstable - your naming convention)  with 3 columns (id (primary, auto increment), fb_user_id (index), fb_friend).  Each time a user adds a friend, you INSERT a row in this table.

Then you generate a report with a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from productstable WHERE product_owner_fb_id IN (SELECT fb_friend from friendstable WHERE fb_user_id = '".$fb_user_id."')";
```